# I can't embed Recaptcha into a email form

Tags: php, html, email, recaptcha

I'm trying to implement a recaptcha into an email form on a site I'm working on, however it's not working and I can't figure out why... I have removed all the recaptcha code and the form works fine, I think my mistake is in the recaptcha handling somewhere, but I'm not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated

this is the form

```
<!-- start contact form -->
                <form method="POST" name="contact_form" action="contact-form-handler.php">
                    <h4>Your Name:</h4>
                    <input type="text" name="name" size="35">
                    <h4>Email Address:</h4>
                    <input type="text" name="email" size="35">
                    <h4>Message:</h4>
                    <textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="37"></textarea>
                    <div>
                        <script type="text/javascript" 
                                src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=publickey">
                        </script>
                        <noscript>
                        <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=publickey"
                                height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
                        <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
                        </textarea>
                        <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
                            value="manual_challenge">
                        </noscript>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                    </div>

                    <script language="JavaScript">
                    var frmvalidator  = new Validator("contact_form");
                    frmvalidator.addValidation("name","req","Please provide your name");
                    frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req","Please provide your email");
                    frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email","Please enter a valid email address");
                    frmvalidator.addValidation("message","req","Please write a message");   
                    frmvalidator.addValidation("recaptcha_challenge_field", "req", "Please answer the captcha test");
                    </script>
                </form>
                <!-- end contact form-->
```

and this is the backend php that processes it...

```
    <?php
require_once('/scripts/recaptcha/recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "PRIVATE KEY";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"], $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
header('Location: contact.html')
exit;

} else {

$myemail = 'myemail';

$to = $myemail;

$email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";

$email_body = "You have received a new message. ".

" Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n ".

"Email: $email_address\n Message \n $message";

$headers = "From: $myemail\n";

$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

$email_body = wordwrap($email_body, 70);

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

header('Location: contact_thanks.html');

exit;

}
?>
```

Comment: follow this document : https://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/wiki/HowToSetUpRecaptcha

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert the keys provided by recaptcha here: `src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=publickey"` and here `src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=publickey"` (replace "publickey" with the public key given by recaptcha)

And put your private key given by recaptcha in the php file here: `$privatekey = "PRIVATE KEY";`

If you still have issues, there are times when recaptcha generates invalid keys, if you are unlucky to get broken keys, you have to wait a day or so for their fix.

To get your keys if you haven't done this yet, register [here](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#whyrecaptcha)

Very important notice from my own experience, if you do get broken keys, the recaptcha won't even show up at all and you will get no error! I had to manually access the links to see that the recaptcha key would return 500 internal server error and I had to wait for them to fix these keys.

Comment: I've done all that, I removed the keys for the purposes of sharing the code... I can get the captcha to display fine, as for the links, they seem to work fine, both display stuff when I put them into a browser...

Comment: You can try to modify how captcha is being shown by using this function `echo recaptcha_get_html($public_key);` see if it works like this (obviously, now the file should be .php).

Comment: I've done that, I think it's possibly something to do with how the data is passed between them or something? I always get redirected to the php file but never beyond that... The email also doesn't send.